# What does this mean in C language?

Tags: c++, c

What does this do in C language and please explain this with simplified example ?

```
void KidLogic::doCommand() 
{  }
```

Comment: This is not `C`, this is `C++`. A similar yet different language.

Comment: Sorry, this is not C,

Comment: Voting to re-open. There is no colon that could be interpreted as prepended to a class name in this question.

Comment: @CharlesBailey The answer to that question does cover this question, I think. Perhaps the title of the original question should be changed?

Comment: @Stijn: That question has nothing to do with this question; nothing in that question explains how the posted code isn't C so none of the answers there are appropriate here. This may not be a great question but it's certainly not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @CharlesBailey I'll also vote to reopen then.

Answer (score 5):

In C, it doesn't mean anything.
This is C++, and it means the `KidLogic` namespace or class has a `doCommand` function doing nothing.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like C++, not C.

It is a definition of the method `doCommand` for class (or namespace) `KidLogic`.